# Java byte array to int function giving negative number

Tags: java, int, arrays

I have a function like so:

```
static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] bytes) {
         return bytes[0] << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);
}
```

Which should convert a byteArray of 4 bytes to an int.

The byte array in hexBinary is:E0C38881

And the expected output should be: 3770910849
But I am getting: -524056447

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You should return a `long` since `int` may overflow. All java primitives are signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3770910849` is higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you require a positive value, use long instead of int.

For example :

```
static long byteArrayToInt(byte[] bytes) {
     return (long)((bytes[0] << 24) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF)) & 0xffffffffL;
}
```

Comment: do u have a function that would work? I can't seem to get it working still

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to get it working:

```
static long getLong(byte[] buf){
        long l = ((buf[0] & 0xFFL) << 24) |
                 ((buf[1] & 0xFFL) << 16) |
                 ((buf[2] & 0xFFL) << 8) |
                 ((buf[3] & 0xFFL) << 0) ;
        return l;
}
```